# Block the Loading of Animated Gifs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension, gif

I am trying to block gif's from loading, specifically animated gifs, but if that is not possible, then all gif's. The point is to reduce bandwidth. I am able to remove elements using `.remove()` and jQuery, but this still means they load. Is there a way to block the specific requests for the gifs so that they do not even load in the first place?

Edit: I am talking about making a Google Chrome extension

Comment: Stop them server-side.

Comment: @TusharGupta what if they're from a different domain?

Comment: @Markasoftware I want to block them with an extension.

Comment: @TusharGupta See my edit. I am making a extension, I do not have control of most of the sites.

Answer (score 0):

You will run into timing issues. If you use a content script you can remove those dom elements but since your extension activates when the page is fully loaded and ready, by then probably chrome already loaded them.
Small animated gifs dont consume much bandwith unless youre talking about the recent trend of making short videos with gifs. For those large ones you might prevent some frames from loading.

Comment: You sure about the timing issues? I did some research and it seems the Chrome API has [chrome.webRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) which when chained I could use `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener()` to intercept the gif requests. Is this not the case? It appears to be what another extension does: [Imgur-to-Gfycat](https://github.com/STRML/Imgur-to-Gfycat/blob/master/Source/bg.js)

Comment: Aha it might be. Post here when you find out. I thought that was for js requests not chrome's own requests.

Comment: Did you take a look at the example I linked to? It looks like they are using the previously stated api to block the loading of GIFs.